# Mount Kubernetes secret at pod runtime

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have an *optional* secret volume defined in my StatefulSet like

```
  - name: my-secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret
      optional: true
```

And further, I mount it in my container. When I provision the pod, the secret does not exist yet.

Later, another service is installed on the cluster, which creates `my-secret`. Is there any way to mount that secret inside my pod where it was originally marked as optional, without having to restart the pod?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, mounted secrets are updated automatically. From https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets :

> When a secret being already consumed in a volume is updated, projected
>   keys are eventually updated as well. Kubelet is checking whether the
>   mounted secret is fresh on every periodic sync.

I have tested it manually, defined `my-secret` and it eventually (in under a minute) showed up in the mounted path, which was previously empty (before I created `my-secret`).